# How to use `as` to convert an object to the a subtype of another two types?

Tags: types, kotlin

Some Kotlin code:

```
interface A
interface B

interface X : A, B
```

So we can use `as` to convert an object to `X`, which is the subtype of `A` and `B`:

```
obj as X
```

But is it possible to do it without declaring the interface `X`?

It may be some fake code:

```
obj as (A & B)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no way.

There has been a discussion on [Interesection Types](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/union-and-intersection-types-feature-request/4191/7). This is where Ceylon shines.